# Cannot subset a dataframe based off 2 conditions using a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, subset

I am trying to subset a datatime:
`my_df = my_df[(my_df['Date'] >= one_hour_ago) & my_df['Date'] <= current_time]`

I am getting the following error:
`datetime64TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]`

I honestly do not understand what is happening right now. What is a `datetime64`? And why is pandas not able to complete this subset?

Answer (score 0):

Missing parantheses for second condition:

```
my_df = my_df[(my_df['Date'] >= one_hour_ago) & (my_df['Date'] <= current_time)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I got poor sleep and completely overlooked this.